# Determine projection of a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system

Is there anyway to determine projection of a shapefile which doesn't have .prj file?

I am trying to re-project this shapefile to another projection, I know that it is Lat long data. I could manage to load this in GIS tools like [this](http://www.mapshaper.org/) or QGIS

[image]

Based on DBF data, it's Auckland data. According to [this link](https://github.com/rcoup/proj4/blob/master/proj/nad/epsg) the EPSG code of New Zealand is 27120 as the picture indicates:

[image]

Also I tried to display a point of this shape in Google Maps and it worked:

[image]

But still not sure what is the projection of this shapefile? I don't think it's WGS84 because I wasn't successful to reproject it from WGS84 to EPSG:27120 which is New Zealand grid system.

If it's not WGS84 how does Google display the point successfully?

The shapefile is [available here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BywY2CmtfVjGVldRN1RhOUlEZjQ/view?usp=sharing), it is small (5KB)

Comment: @Joseph Thank you very much. 
Maybe you can post it as answer then I can mark it as accepted.
The problem was choosing wrong projection for destination projection.

Comment: Most welcome buddy! I posted the comment as an answer and I'm glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you can obtain a shapefiles initial CRS but you can reproject your shapefile to another New Zealand grid system (**EPSG:27200** - NZGD49 / New Zealand Map Grid) via the **Save As...** option.

I used QGIS 2.6.1 to successfully reproject the shapefile:

[image: Projected shapefile]